# Reading COM port in c++, getting errors

Tags: c++, serial-port

First time poster long time reader.

I've been playing round with reading in data from a bluetooth GPS unit.
I can connect to it using hyperterm and see the data

**The following log is from the hyperterm**

```
$GPRMC,195307.109,A,5208.2241,N,00027.7689,W,000.0,345.8,310712,,,A*7E
$GPVTG,345.8,T,,M,000.0,N,000.0,K,A*07
$GPGGA,195308.109,5208.2242,N,00027.7688,W,1,04,2.1,58.9,M,47.3,M,,0000*7E
$GPGSA,A,3,19,03,11,22,,,,,,,,,5.5,2.1,5.0*3F
$GPRMC,195308.109,A,5208.2242,N,00027.7688,W,000.0,345.8,310712,,,A*73
$GPVTG,345.8,T,,M,000.0,N,000.0,K,A*07
$GPGGA,195309.109,5208.2243,N,00027.7688,W,1,04,2.1,58.9,M,47.3,M,,0000*7E
```

**END LOG**

**The following log is from my C++ program**

```
$GPGSV,3,3,12,14,20,105,16,28,18,323,,08,07,288,,16,01,178,*7A

$GPRMC,195,3,2ÿþÿÿÿL.š945.109,A,5208.2386,N,00027.7592,W,000.0,169.5,8,323,,08,07,288,,16,01,178,*7A

$GPRMC,195,3,2ÿþÿÿÿL.š310712,,,A*70

$GPVTG,169.5,T,,M,000.0,N,000.0,K,A*06

8,07,288,,16,01,178,*7A

$GPRMC,195,3,2ÿþÿÿÿL.š310712,,,A*70

$GPVTG,169.5,T,,M,000.0,N,000.0,K,A*06

8,07,288,,16,01,178,*7A

$GPRMC,195,3,2ÿþÿÿÿL.š$GPGGA,195946.109,5208.2386,N,00027.7592,W,1.0,K,A*06

8,07,288,,16,01,178,*7A
```

**END LOG**

**THE PROBLEM**
I've left the line feeds as they come, the C++ output has extra line feeds, not sure why?
The C++ log also has some funky chars...?

**The Code**

```
    for (int n=0;n<100;n++) {
        char INBUFFER[100];
        cv::waitKey(1000);
        bStatus = ReadFile(comport,   // Handle
                &INBUFFER,            // Incoming data
                100,                  // Number of bytes to read
                &bytes_read,          // Number of bytes read
                NULL);

        cout << "bStatus " << bStatus << endl;
        if (bStatus != 0)
        {
            // error processing code goes here
        }
        LogFile << INBUFFER;
    }
```

I'm using settings...

```
    comSettings.BaudRate = 2400;
    comSettings.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    comSettings.ByteSize = 8;
    comSettings.Parity   = NOPARITY;
    comSettings.fParity  = FALSE;
```

...which as far as I can tell are the same as the settings used by hyperterm.
Any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

cheers!

**UPDATE**
So after updating to use bytes_read and account for the extra LF at the end of NMEA data I now have...

```
    if (bytes_read!=0) {
        for (int i=0; i < bytes_read; i++) {
            LogFile << INBUFFER[i];
        }
    }
```

Which appears to have fixed things!

```
$GPGGA,215057.026,5208.2189,N,00027.7349,W,1,04,6.8,244.6,M,47.3,M,,0000*41
$GPGSA,A,3,32,11,01,19,,,,,,,,,9.7,6.8,7.0*3D
$GPRMC,215057.026,A,5208.2189,N,00027.7349,W,002.0,208.7,310712,,,A*74
$GPVTG,208.7,T,,M,002.0,N,003.8,K,A*09
$GPGGA,215058.026,5208.2166,N,00027.7333,W,1,04,6.8,243.1,M,47.3,M,,0000*42
```

Thanks folks, your help was much appreciated.

Comment: Does your `error processing code goes here` really look like that, or are you checking for errors? If so, do you get any? By the way... `INBUFFER`: ugh! Don't use all uppercase names for variables - keep them for `#define` symbols.

Comment: no, I'm not doing any error checking at the mo. Cheers, I'll take note of the case change.

Comment: The extra line feeds may be because the GPS sends a CR/LF sequence at the end of each line, and that may get interpreted as two separate linefeed character. see here. http://www.hemispheregps.com/gpstechinfo/NMEA_0183_Message_Format.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `bytes_read` var, but you don't do anything with it?  Seems to me that you're dumping the entire `INBUFFER` to the file, no matter how many/few bytes are actually loaded into it?

Comment: Thanks, i'm now doing.

if (bytes_read!=0) {
    for (int i=0; i <= bytes_read; i++) {
 LogFile << INBUFFER[i];
     }
}

which has cleaned things up a little.

But I'm still getting the odd error here and there

$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,20.0,20.0,20.0*02

$,GPRMC,210435.193,V,5209.9306,N,00027.1293,W,075.8,356.6,310712,,,N*6A

$GPVTG,356.6,T,,M,075.8,NT,140.4,K,N*0F

3$GPGGA,210436.193,5209.9306,N,00027.1293,W,00,00,20.0,106.4,M,47.3,M,,0000*79


---- Sorry, is it better to update my post above with any results or post them below?

Comment: ...and in particular if `ReadFile` actually reads 100 bytes, you're writing random garbage off the end of the buffer as well.

Comment: @Oliver9523 - usually best to update the post, or add to it, so earlier answers still make some sort of sense!